# Widget is being rebuilt when Child Widget is calling a Push Named

Tags: dart, flutter

## This is My Home Screen Widget Build

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Rebuilt root widget");
  switch (authStatus) {
    case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
      return Child1(
        auth: widget.auth,
        onSignedIn: _signedIn,
      );
    case AuthStatus.signedIn:
      return Child2(
        auth: widget.auth,
        onSignedOut: _signedOut,
      );
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

## This is a strip of code being called from my "Child2" Widget

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/OtherScreen');
```

When the "OtherScreen" Widget is pushed, the text *Rebuilt root widget* is printed again, implying my root widget is being rebuilt. Why is this so?

Comment: You need to tell some things clearly when u ask a question .. What do you mean when u say "Root" widget , "Home Screen "Widget and "Other Screen" widget ??Please add the tree just to tell which is a parent widget and which is the child widget and you are calling which widget from which one ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's currently a bug (or at least an oversight).  Flutter will rebuild a parent widget, needlessly, upon both a push and a pop.  There's already a github issue filed.

Comment: Link to the issue? There are cases where this is actually normal

Comment: I believe this is the issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655

Comment: @RémiRousselet Can you pls tell cases where this is normal? Also, the purpose of using 'Providers' fails if the build is called again. Consider a case where I listen to my data changes with the help of 'Providers' and the data change is done in a widget added with Navigator. This defeats the purpose of using Providers; I can use the static class level data instead.

Comment: @Vikalp The purpose of `provider` has never been about optimizing rebuilds

Comment: @RémiRousselet Consider a case where I am using ChangeNotifierProvider<T> in Widget A to update the part of my widget tree with the help of Consumers. Then I navigate to Widget B with the help of Navigator.pushNamed(). Here, I make changes to my data <T> and then pop the Widget B. Now if Widget A is to rebuild again then the purpose of using a Consumer failed which was listening to data changes. To be precise, If the consumer does not get notified of data changes but created again during rebuild of Widget A then it is just acting as a one-time bridge b/w data and my widget.

Comment: @RémiRousselet wrong assumption, it can make the difference also in terms of logic